# There is already an object in the database Exception

Tags: c#, mysql, sqlbulkcopy

What's wrong with my code... I tried several things but getting the same error again and again.

Any help??
The Code is:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[SubDomainName].ToString());
conn.Open();
string temptable = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tmptablenew]([TicketID] [int] NULL,[TicketDescription][varchar](max) NULL,[TicketAssignedTo] [varchar](100) NULL,[TicketCreatedDate] [datetime] NULL,[TicketStatus][varchar](50),CRMConnectionID [int] NULL,[TicketUpdatedDate] [Datetime] NULL,img [varchar](500) NULL)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(temptable, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Tickets", conn);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmmd);
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable("dt1");
adapter.Fill(dt1);
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//BulkCopy the data in the DataTable to the temp table
using (SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn))
{
    bulk.DestinationTableName = "Tmptablenew";
    bulk.WriteToServer(result);
    conn.Close();
}
conn.Open();
string mergeSql = "merge into Tickets as Target " +
                     "using Tmptablenew as Source " +
                     "on " +
                     "Target.TicketID= Source.TicketID " +
                     "and Target.CRMConnectionID = Source.CRMConnectionID " +
                     "when not matched then " +
                     "insert (TicketID,TicketDescription,TicketAssignedTo,TicketCreatedDate,TicketStatus,CRMConnectionID,TicketUpdatedDate,img) values (Source.TicketID,Source.TicketDescription,Source.TicketAssignedTo,Source.TicketCreatedDate,Source.TicketStatus,Source.CRMConnectionID,Source.TicketUpdatedDate,Source.img);";

string mergesql1 = "Update Tickets SET TicketDescription=S.TicketDescription, TicketAssignedTo = S.TicketAssignedTo, TicketStatus = S.TicketStatus,TicketUpdatedDate = S.TicketUpdatedDate,img = S.img FROM Tickets t JOIN Tmptablenew AS S ON t.TicketID = S.TicketID and T.CRMConnectionID = S.CRMConnectionID";
cmd.CommandText = mergeSql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmmd.CommandText = mergesql1;
cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.CommandText = "drop table Tmptablenew";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
//Clean up the temp table
conn.Close();
```

Comment: do something with code and describe the problem, please

Comment: What is the _error_? On which line? We need more details..

Comment: Clearly there is "already an object in the database".  You can't create an object with the same name as one which already exists.  So either get rid of the one that already exists or don't try to create a new one.

Comment: Take your inline SQL and execute it with values inside SQL management studio- my guess is there is something wrong with your merge transaction. I would also move that to a stored proc.

Comment: There's only one line that tries to create anything, and that's the third. `Tmptablenew` already exists.

Comment: I didn't even see that- yeah you can't create another table. Also calling something temptable is not the same as #tempTable or ##tempTable or table variable @tempTable

Answer (score 1):

You are creating table `Tmptablenew`, it looks like this table alredy exists in database.

I think, you are trying to create a temporary table, in this case create it as `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` for MySQL or use table name `#Tmptablenew` for MS SQL. Also in this case it will be dropped automatically when session is closed.

**EDIT**

So, you have to change `string temptable = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE [dbo].[Tmptablenew]([TicketID]...` and so on if you are using **MySQL** (as per tag of your question). Or if it is **MS SQL** (as I suspect) then `string temptable = "CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Tmptablenew]([TicketID]...` and so on (and in this case you should name it `#Tmptablenew` everywhere in your code).

Comment: I'm not fluent in My SQL, but google will help you loads here for learning how to create this. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: I tried with ur code now i got the Following Exception,   The Error is System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot access destination table 'Tmptablenew'. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Tmptablenew'.

Comment: @user3226735 Let's clarify. Are you using mysql as it said on your question tag, or mssql? Then, if it's MS Sql - have you changed all occurences of `Tmptablenew` to `#Tmptablenew` in your code? And `DestinationTableName` of SqlBulkCopy too.

Comment: Am using MSSql, I tried with #tmptablenew i got that exception which i mentioned in previous comment.

Comment: @user3226735 Have you changed `bulk.DestinationTableName` to "#Tmptablenew"? It looks like exception you've provided has it source in `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: @user3226735 Revised your code and found one more issue. You should not close connection after `bulk.WriteToServer(result);` and later open it again, as temporary table will only be visible while connection in which it was created, is open.

Comment: I tried in bulk.destinationTable but still same error

Comment: I think you need to check up on some SQL tutorials. I'm not saying that to be mean; this is basic sql transaction material. Use SQL Management studio and test queries. Practice. You need to check out temp tables and table variables and transactions. This seems to be a knowledgeable article https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/